# How to run a nohup script with upstart?

Tags: upstart, nohup

I'm porting some SysV-style service scripts for [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) (a java service) to upstart.

The sysv scripts don't call `java` directly, but instead call `hbase-daemon.sh`. This is a `start-stop-daemon`-like tool that ships with the package which pulls in a lot of configuration and ultimately ends in a `nohup java ... &` to actually run the process as a daemon.

Since the configuration logic in `hbase-daemon.sh` is involved, I would rather not modify or rewrite it (to remove the `nohup`) and instead have upstart call it directly.

This *seems* to be what the [`expect`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect) clause is for, except in my case it isn't working.  Even with `expect daemon` (the two fork case), I end up [tracking the wrong pid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#recovery-on-misspecification-of-expect) on service start.  This suggests that my scenario is forking too much, or perhaps `nohup` shouldn't be handled with `expect`, or yet something else.

How can I use upstart to manage a service that expects to be started with a script that calls `nohup`?

Comment: can you post script source? what if the system user executes it instead?

Comment: https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/55d6a01/bin/hbase-daemon.sh#L144-L146

Comment: no experience with this myself, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501702/running-bash-script-in-upstart-conf-script) seems rather ok-ish? Could you provide the upstart .conf if that `exec` part doesn't work? I could easily try and reproduce with a dummy-script running a `nohup sleep 500`? :-)

Answer (score -1):

You could try using crontab, and enter this in the terminal:

```
 crontab -f nohup
```

and then enter this:

```
 pyton(version) -v -f echo 'nohup' & disown
```

and then enter this in the terminal:

```
 crontab reboot
```

and it might work fine this way.